# Canonical "do I need to recheck luggage?" question

Tags: discussion, duplicates, canonical-questions

The question of whether one needs to recheck luggage at an intermediate stop on a multileg journey seems to show up at least once every other day, if not more often. Do we have a canonical question we can close these as duplicates of, or an existing question/answer that might be adapted or expanded to become the canonical?

In my opinion, the ideal answer would cover:
- single ticket versus multiple ticket
- code shares
- US-specific scenarios (including territories like Puerto Rico, etc)
- other edge cases?

Comment: I fear this could be a bit like having a "canonical visa question". There's going to be too many cases to put in one answer. The current system of closing exact dupes and answering fresh questions is probably already the optimal way to handle them. But if there are some general rules of thumb across the board it could be handy to know but might we risk wrongful dupe closures to such an answer, which would necessarily be incomplete?

Comment: The new questions really just boil down to a question/answer session of is this one ticket or multiples, and then an answer based on that. Edge cases like multiple tickets and airlines but there happens to be an agreement i n place between them could be answered separately.